# DLL problem while running a program in wine

Tags: 14.04, wine

I have a 64 bit host system and installed wine using `sudo apt-get install wine1.6`. I created a new 32 bit prefix like so: `WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine winecfg`.
Then I ran the installer of the software I wanted to install. It exited without any errors. I ran `wineboot` to 'reboot' wine and then launched the installed program.

Nothing showed up so I tried running `wine Toris32.EXE` manually in the installation path and got the following error:
[paste](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7898142/).

It seems like the path variable to system32 isn't set up properly. What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Where did you get the program from 9and what is it), and have you tried Wine 1.7? Also, have you tried setting in Windows version in wineconfig to a later version of Windows?

Comment: It is a software for organizing tournaments. I got it from [here](http://www.pferd-aktuell.de/toris/installation-und-update/installation) which is the official download site. Changing windows versions didn't help. I'll try wine1.7 and report back.

Comment: Nope, I get the exact same errors using wine1.7.